# select some fields in eagerload

Tags: join, sqlalchemy, pylons

I have two tables:

```
class Auto(Base):

    __tablename__ = "auto"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    added = Column(DateTime())
```

and

```
class Url(Base):

    __tablename__ = "url"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    added = Column(DateTime())
    auto_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('auto.id'))
    url = Column(Unicode(500))
    content = Column(UnicodeText())

    auto = relation('Auto', backref=backref('url', order_by=id))
```

I selecting data with

```
Session.query(Auto).options(eagerload('url')).limit(20)
```

In select statement i get all fields relative to Auto and Url tables, but i want to select only some results (Auto.id, Auto.added, Url.id, Url.added).
Problem is what in Url.content store large amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you are using option `eagerload()` for relations, there is an option `defer()` for column properties to disable loading them untill they are accessed:

```
session.query(Auto).options(joinedload('url'), defer('url.content')).limit(20)
```